# Call a function (with parameters) inside a v-for element (Vue.js)

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm trying to generate a select (with Vue.js and Material Design) with 2 levels (categories and items). A category can have X items (selected or not).

```
<md-select v-if="categories.length > 0" name="categories" id="categories" multiple > 
    <div v-for="(category,key,index) in categories" :key="category.id">
       <md-subheader>{{category.name}}</md-subheader>
       <md-option 
          v-if="category.subItems" 
          v-for="subItem in category.subItems" 
          :key="subItem.id" 
          :value="subItem.id"
          selected="checkIsSelected(subItem.id)">
           {{subItem.name}}
       </md-option>      
     </div>
</md-select>
```

This generates a select like:

```
   Category 1
      [ ] - Item 1
      [x] - Item 2
      [ ] - Item 3
   Category 2
      ...
```

**The problem** I have is when I try to check if the item is already selected (from an API) I'm using the method:

> selected="checkIsSelected(subItem.id)"

And in my `methods: {`

```
methods: {

...

  checkIsSelected (catId) {
    this.selectedOld.map((catOld) => {
      if (catId === catOld.id) {
        return true
      }
    })
    return false
  }
}
```

In a brief:

> How I can call a function (with parameters) inside a element of a
>   v-for in order to check/uncheck the element?

But this function is never called. What I'm doing wrong? I tried some other thinks but didn't work either.

I will appreciate your help, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally I resolved myself with a different approach. Hope maybe helps someone.

Instead of calling a function in the `for option` I previously call the API to check if it's previously selected and add an attribute to the subItem element.

With the @Ricardo Orellana solution in the first load, I can't know which item is selected, only when the `select` value change.

I use the `v-bind:class` option to check if the subItem is selected and mark:

```
   <md-select v-if="categories.length > 0" name="categories" id="categories" multiple v-model="selectedNew"> 
      <md-button class="md-icon-button" md-menu-trigger slot="icon">
        <md-icon>{{icon}}</md-icon>      
      </md-button>

      <div v-for="(category,key,index) in categories" :key="category.id">
        <md-subheader>{{category.name}}</md-subheader>
        <md-option 
          v-bind:class="{ 'md-checked' : subItem.selected }"
          v-if="category.subItems" 
          v-for="subItem in category.subItems"
          :key="subItem.id" 
          :value="subItem">
            {{subItem.name}}
        </md-option>      
      </div>
    </md-select>
```

Then, in the `method` part:

```
   ...
   cat.subItems = actobj                
   cat.subItems.map(this.markIsSelected)
   ...

   markIsSelected (cat, index, categories) {
      categories[index].selected = false
      this.selectedOld.forEach(function (catOld) {
        if (cat.id === catOld.optionId) {
          categories[index].selected = true
          return
        }
      })
    }
```

Thanks for your time and the help!

Comment: Thanks for posting your solution and thinking about helping others!

Answer (score 1):

You could try to add `v-model="currentCategorySelected"` and use the function `@change="checkIsSelected"`. That way anytime a new option is selected is going to execute and pass the id selected through the callback.

This should work:

```
<md-select
  v-if="categories.length > 0"
  name="categories"
  id="categories"
  v-model="currentCategorySelected"
  @change="checkIsSelected"
  multiple>
    <div 
      v-for="(category,key,index) in categories"
      :key="category.id">

      <md-subheader>
        {{category.name}}
      </md-subheader>

      <md-option
        v-if="category.subItems"
        v-for="subItem in category.subItems"
        :key="subItem.id"
        :value="subItem.id"
      >
        {{subItem.name}}
      </md-option>
    </div>
</md-select>
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to change `selected="checkIsSelected(subItem.id)"` to `:selected="checkIsSelected(subItem.id)"`. Colon.

Comment: It's still not working... I can't call the checkIsSelected method.